# building a logical condition query with else and if android sqlite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I'm using filtering and the only filter that is implemented is a search by key_name, I'd like to also add other keys.

```
 public static Cursor fetchCountriesByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
      Log.w(TAG, inputText);
      Cursor c = null;
      if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
       c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
         KEY_NAME, KEY_COUNTRY, KEY_REGION, KEY_PHONE},
         null, null, null, null, null);

      }
      else  {
      c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
         KEY_NAME, KEY_COUNTRY, KEY_REGION, KEY_PHONE},
         KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
         null, null, null, null);
      }

      if (c != null) {
       c.moveToFirst();
      }
      return c;

     }
```

when i tried to use else { if ( it requested a (c != null), when i tried to modify, KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null, KEY_COUNTRY + " like '%" + inputText + "%'",KEY_REGION + " like '%" + inputText + "%'"); was saying illegalargumentexception.

How to do it right?

Thanks.

Comment: add your full query for which you are getting error

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add condition like `AND`or `OR` in  your query

check below example

```
    db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                     KEY_NAME, KEY_COUNTRY, KEY_REGION, KEY_PHONE}, 
                     KEY_NAME + " LIKE ? AND ", KEY_COUNTRY + " LIKE ? AND ", KEY_REGION + " LIKE ?",
                     new String[] {"%"+inputText+"%" ,"%"+inputText+"%" ,"%"+inputText+"%"}, 
                     null, null, null, null);
```

here i have used `AND` you can replace it as your need.

Comment: then it throws: The method query(boolean, String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String, String, CancellationSignal) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (boolean, String, String[], String[], String[], null, null, null, null, null)

Comment: @kTN yes you can get more options but main thing condition .